# java - Using Picasso for getting image from url with json - androidstudio

Tags: java, android

i'm using JSON for requesting text and put it in a list view with custom adapter, here is my code so far..

```
  private class getMovies extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(alrehabfilms.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        http sh = new http();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        // Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray moviesp90 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("moviesalrehab");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < moviesp90.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = moviesp90.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String actors = c.getString("actors");
                    String tandp = c.getString("prizeandtime");
                    String img = c.getString("img"); //here is for the image



                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject pref = c.getJSONObject("pref");
                    String imrating = pref.getString("imrating");
                    String genre = pref.getString("genre");
                    String guide = pref.getString("guide");
                    String director = pref.getString("director");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> movie = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    movie.put("id", id);
                    movie.put("name", name);
                    movie.put("actors", actors);
                    movie.put("prizeandtime", tandp);
                    if(img != null && !img.equalsIgnoreCase(""))                           Picasso.with(alrehabfilms.this).load(img).into(imggg); //here idk how to put like movie.put("img", Picasso code)
                    movie.put("imrating", imrating);
                    movie.put("genre", genre);
                    movie.put("guide", guide);
                    movie.put("director", director);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    alrehabmovieList.add(movie);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                //  Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "An error happened, please try again!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            //     Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Failed to retrieve data, please check your internet connection",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(alrehabfilms.this);




                    adb.setTitle("No internet connection");



                    adb.setMessage("Would you like to try to gather data again?");
                    adb.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            new getMovies().execute();


                        } });


                    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            finish();
                        } });
                    adb.show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                alrehabfilms.this, alrehabmovieList,
                R.layout.imgtest, new String[]{"name", "actors",
                "prizeandtime", "img", "imrating", "genre","guide", "director"}, new int[]{R.id.movieName,
                R.id.movieActors, R.id.moviePrizeAndTime, R.id.imggg//imageeview, R.id.movieRating, R.id.movieGenre,R.id.pGuid, R.id.dir});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

}

As you see here, i put this line for the image

```
   String img = c.getString("img"); //here is for the image
```

My problem here is how to put it in that way

```
movie.put("img", THECODEIWANT);
```

instead of this,

```
  if(img != null && !img.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        Picasso.with(alrehabfilms.this).load(img).into(imggg);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to directly put the image in the array?

You can do that but it will block your app while it gets real Bitmap image data from Picasso.

That is why we are using Picasso to asynchronously load image in the background thread.

Comment: Well, i want to put that image in the listview according its movie which is at the json file.. if i put by your way, i won't be listed as it should be. Have you got any idea how to put it?

Comment: I mean what about loading images when it really need to be? If I were you I will load images with Picasso inside of Custom List Adapter when getView method is called.

Comment: Please see this tutorial. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-adapter-use-for-listview-gridview-etc It will be helpful.